# Why here used return; in catch block?

Tags: java, exception, return, try-catch

Why there is using **return;** keyword and what will happen when there will not use **return;**

**i know that will go end of the function** but still i don't understand what is meaning of that.
It's used at the main method how it will be go end of the main method???

```
try {
         //some code
    }
 
catch (//...) {
        
         return;  //why here using return; keyword
    }
```

Comment: `return;` will just exit the entire method.  If there is any more code after the try/catch, it'll be skipped.

Comment: What Louis said.  I would add that this is very bad form.  You should either re-throw the exception or wrap the exception in a new exception and throw that.

Comment: @Ryan This is not bad form at all. Often there's situations where simply returning when an error happened is OK. You're right, USUALLY handling (passing the exception with extra details) is the way to go. But not on all occasions. The problem is that the question does not offer enough inside into the real workings of the code, just asking this abstract question (that should be completely clear with basic Java knowledge and some experience.)

Comment: **Thank you** Mr. @LouisWasserman iam clear with your comment.

Comment: @JayC667 If I saw that in a peer review it would get failed and told to re-write.  Exceptions should never be buried.  If an exception is to exit a method early, then throw the exception to notify the caller.  Failing to do will cause headaches down the road.

Comment: What, if by interface contract, the method is not supposed/allowed to throw Exceptions, but instead return an error value? There's enough examples out there - just think of application return codes or interop error signaling or the whole ISO model protocol stack. You wanna partake in any of those, you better not throw exceptions, but handle them. What about a "testConnection" method for example? It's supposed to test and return a value or call some callback function, NOT throw an exception. And as I said, the whole context is missing, so who are we to judge?